# Airflow 2.x bucket and range argument for ExternalTable(Ghseets) Operator from Gsheets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am having problems using the new Airflow operator `BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator` within Google-Composer:

Question 1

After creating an Airflow task this is happening :

```
AttributeError: 'BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator' object has no attribute 'bucket'
```

However, as I am querying a gsheets file why it is looking for bucket argument? I am getting crazy trying to find what is happening! According to the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html#howto-operator-bigquerycreateexternaltableoperator) it is optional!

Sample Code

```
task1 = BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator(
        task_id="task1_externaltable",
        table_resource={
            "tableReference": {
                "projectId": projectid,
                "datasetId": datasetid,
                "tableId": tableid,
            },
            "schema": schema_fields,
            "externalDataConfiguration": {
                "sourceFormat": "GOOGLE_SHEETS",
                "autodetect": False,
                "compression": "NONE",
                "googleSheetsOptions": {
                    "skipLeadingRows": 1,
                    "range": gsheets_tab_name,
                },
                "sourceUris": gsheets_url,
            },
        },
    )
```

Following Elad's suggestion, error traceback!:

```
AttributeError: 'BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator' object has no attribute 'bucket'
[2022-03-18, 14:45:38 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1268} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=trm_analytics_attribution_collision_checker_dag, task_id=create_manual_attribution_2_external_table, execution_date=20220318T144520, start_date=20220318T144536, end_date=20220318T144538
[2022-03-18, 14:45:38 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:89} ERROR - Failed to execute job 444 for task create_manual_attribution_2_external_table
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/task/task_runner/standard_task_runner.py", line 85, in _start_by_fork
    args.func(args, dag=self.dag)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 302, in task_run
    _run_task_by_selected_method(args, dag, ti)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 107, in _run_task_by_selected_method
    _run_raw_task(args, ti)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 180, in _run_raw_task
    ti._run_raw_task(
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
    return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1330, in _run_raw_task
    self._execute_task_with_callbacks(context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1420, in _execute_task_with_callbacks
    self.render_templates(context=context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1995, in render_templates
    self.task.render_template_fields(context)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1061, in render_template_fields
    self._do_render_template_fields(self, self.template_fields, context, jinja_env, set())
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/baseoperator.py", line 1072, in _do_render_template_fields
    content = getattr(parent, attr_name)
AttributeError: 'BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator' object has no attribute 'bucket'
[2022-03-18, 14:45:38 UTC] {local_task_job.py:154} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-03-18, 14:45:38 UTC] {local_task_job.py:264} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: Hi OP, can you confirm if your gsheets URI is in this format `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID`?

Comment: what version of google provider do you use?

Comment: Please show full traceback of the error

Comment: @Elad I am using Composer 1.18.0 and Airflow 2.2.3, already installed in the env the latest pipy google cloud providers

Comment: @ScottB the URL is in that format:     default_var="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/string",

Comment: I suggest to open a bug report to Airflow

Comment: Just provided full traceback of the error.

Comment: @DonCharlie please open bug report for this https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues

Comment: Hi OP, I tried to create a `BigQueryCreateExternalTableOperator` task using the exact sample code you provided (using gsheets URI and not putting it on a bucket) also using the same environment config for the composer environment you mentioned in comments and it worked without any issues on my end. Have you tried creating a new composer environment and then retry your python code?